# QPushButton to open QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, class, qwidget, qpushbutton

I created 2 windows with Qt Designer and I want in the first window with the button "..." open the second window properly. I tried to do this, thank you for help.

**firstwindow.cpp**

```
#include "firstwindow.h"
#include "ui_firstwindow.h"
#include "secondwindow.h"
#include "ui_secondwindow.h"

FirstWindow::FirstWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FirstWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->buttonapply->setText("Valider");
    ui->buttoncancel->setText("Annuler");
    ui->buttonetc->setText("...");
    ui->buttonnext->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Haut.png"));
    ui->buttonprevious->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Bas.png"));

    connect(ui->buttonetc, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ShowSecondWindow()));
}

FirstWindow::~FirstWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void    FirstWindow::ShowSecondWindow()
{
    SecondWindow    window;

    window.show();
}
```

**firstwindow.h**

```
#ifndef FIRSTWINDOW_H
#define FIRSTWINDOW_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QIcon>
#include "secondwindow.h"
#include "ui_secondwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class FirstWindow;
}

class FirstWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FirstWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FirstWindow();

public slots:
    void ShowSecondWindow();

private:
    Ui::FirstWindow *ui;
    SecondWindow *window;
};

#endif // FIRSTWINDOW_H
```

**secondwindow.cpp**

```
#include "firstwindow.h"
#include "ui_firstwindow.h"
#include "secondwindow.h"
#include "ui_secondwindow.h"

SecondWindow::SecondWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SecondWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

SecondWindow::~SecondWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**secondwindow.h**

```
#ifndef SECONDWINDOW_H
#define SECONDWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "firstwindow.h"
#include "ui_firstwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class SecondWindow;
}

class SecondWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SecondWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SecondWindow();

private:
    Ui::SecondWindow *ui;
};

#endif // SECONDWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "firstwindow.h"
#include "ui_firstwindow.h"
#include "secondwindow.h"
#include "ui_secondwindow.h"

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication    program(argc, argv);
    FirstWindow     window;

    window.setWindowTitle("BASELFI - Programme - © 2016 H2A");
    window.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Images/Bouclier.png"));
    window.setFixedSize(340, 270);
    window.show();
    return program.exec();
}
```

Comment: `window` is a local variable in your handler, so it gets destroyed immediatly when the function ends. Either create an instance of `SecondWindow` with new and store the pointer somewhere, or use `doModal()` if the second window is a dialog and should only exist for a short time.

Comment: @KarstenKoop, Maybe may you write some code. It will be an example in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
void FirstWindow::ShowSecondWindow()
    {
        SecondWindow    window;

        window.show();
    }
```

The moment this function exits, the SecondWindow object will close immediately. since its only created on stack which will be automatically destroyed when goes out of scope.

to fix this, you must allocate it on the heap/stack as data member on your FirstWindow class or make it static

**Allocate to heap and make it data member:**

```
class FirstWindow
{
....
private:
     SecondWindow* window; // you must delete this in destructor
};
void FirstWindow::ShowSecondWindow()
{ 
      window = new SecondWindow;
      window->show();
}
```

**or Make it static:**

```
void FirstWindow::ShowSecondWindow()
{ 
      static SecondWindow window;
      window.show();
}
```

**or 
Allocate to stack and make it data member to FirstWindow class:**

```
class FirstWindow
{
....
private:
     SecondWindow window; // initialize in constructor
};
 void FirstWindow::ShowSecondWindow()
 { 
       window.show();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: @Meugiwara if this solved your problem you should mark it as solved

Comment: I have exactly the same error "SecondWindow does not name a type", but you helped me to write properly.

Comment: @Meugiwara you didnt state it on the OP, either way its because your FirstWindow doesnt see your SecondWindow class

Comment: How can I do because I created the two windows separately with Qt Designer also I get two Qt Designer Interface.

Comment: Its alright as long as they are on the same project.try removing #include "firstwindow.h"
#include "ui_firstwindow.h" in both SecondWindow.cpp and SecondWindow.h
then clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the famous include problem.